# How to get UIView subclass to take available space in a Stack View

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios10, uistackview

As part of my UI I have a horizontal stack view that contains two vertical stack views. The first vertical contains two labels. The second vertical contains two of my custom UIView subclasses – let's call them MyUIView.

```
+---------+-------------------+
| Label 1 |                ## |
| Label 2 |                ## |
+---------+-------------------+
```

What I am trying to achieve (in IB if possible) is that the left side of the horizontal stack be sized to the intrinsic size of the (largest of the) labels, and the right side take all of the available remaining width. Which is to say the MyUIViews should expand to that width. So no matter how wide the screen I would have "wide enough" labels and MyUIViews taking the rest.

However no matter what I try, both in IB and at runtime, the MyUIViews are small or invisible in width.

I suspect the issue is my custom views do not have an intrinsic content size, but I'm stuck as to how to address this properly. I feel like the horizontal stack should be set to "Fill proportional" but how do I tell the MyUIViews to "go all the way"?

Comment: I have tried and implement same requirement  as you have but I don't have any problem with the width of both the Vertical Stack View.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and implement same requirement as you have but I don't have any problem with the width of both the Vertical Stack View.

I just put ***Hotizontal*** : **Content Compression Resistance Priority** to the label of the first vertical stack View to **751** for achieving the dynamic width.

[image]

Comment: Well, I checked and they already had CCRP of 751. This was an old constraints-based layout so maybe some of that was left over.

Comment: However, while playing with those settings against the different distribution modes I noticed that IB did not always properly reflect my changes in the display. I'd have my zero-width bars on Fill Proportionally, change to Fill Equally and they'd stretch half the width, then change back and the bars would stay half way.

So... I decided to try running again with each setting to see what runtime would provide. Turns out "Fill" does the job perfectly. Go figure.